# Getting cell value from table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with no id or name inside of a div.  How do I read the value from the desired table cell in jQuery?  For example:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="padding-top: 0px; height: 60px;">
<table width="264" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td width="80" height="20" style="font-size: 10px;">
  </td>
  <td id="the_cell_i_want" align="right" style="color: rgb(102, 188, 41); font-size: 24px;font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: none;">THE_VALUE_I_WANT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the cell with the id "the_cell_i_want" and it should return "THE_VALUE_I_WANT".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#the_cell_i_want").text();
```

will do it for you.

Since you have the id you can uniquely select the element from the DOM using the [id selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/id#id). And you can get the cell value [innerText] using [text](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text).